# error in Getting image file's size and dimensions in jquery, ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

I have a file control, By selecting an image using the file control i need to get the image's size and dimensions.

HTML code :

```
<input type="file"  id="button_background_image_control"  />
```

JQuery Code :

```
$('#button_background_image_control').bind('change', function () 
    {             
        if (this.disabled) 
        {
            alert('Your browser does not support File upload.');
        } else 
        {
            var chosen = this.files[0];
            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function () 
            {
                alert('Width:' + this.width + ' Height:' + this.height + ' ' + Math.round(chosen.size / 1024) + 'KB');
            }; 
            image.src = url.createObjectURL(chosen);
        }
    });
```

While running the above code in ie8 i am getting an error : 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.files.0' is null or not an object

In firefox it works fine. How can i make it work in ie???

Comment: This is using the HTML5 File API, and that is only implemented in IE 10. If you need a solution that works in IE < 10, then you’ll have to look for something proprietary (VBScript, Active-X maybe), or use Flash or a JAVA applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because IE8 doesn't support the HTML5 File API, which is being used by this code.

If you need to support it, there are some polyfill scripts that might help you by adding the missing functionality (or parts of it) to older browsers -- Try reading through the [Modernizr Polyfills list](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) page and find the *File API* section.

There are several scripts there which claim to help with file handling in older browsers, but you'll need to try them all out for yourself to see which one suits your needs the best.

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there any other way to get the image's size and dimensions in ie8 and less